# React-select correct onchange value type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have basic select component like this.

```
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select, { StylesConfig } from "react-select";
//..

const [universe, setUniverse] = useState<SetStateAction<TOption | unknown>>(null);

<Controller
    name="universe_id"
    control={control} // this control is imported from react-hook-form nothing special
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Select
            {...field}
            value={universe}
            onChange={handleUniverseChange}
            options={universeOptions}
            styles={selectStyles as StylesConfig}
        />
    )}
/>
```

And `TOption` type

```
export type TOption = {
  label: string | number;
  value: string | number;
};
```

Problem is that I can't set correct type for change handler value.

```
const handleUniverseChange = (item: unknown ) => {
    setUniverse(item);
    setValue("universe_id", item.value); // object type is unknown
};
```

Try to use `TOption` type for item also does not work.

```
const handleUniverseChange = (item: TOption) => {
```

Getting error in this line

```
<Select
    {...field}
    value={universe}
    onChange={handleUniverseChange}
```

> Error: Type "(item: TOption) => void" can't assign for "(newValue:
> unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta) => void".

Comment: Are you using any frontend UI framework like Antd or MUI ??

Comment: @SujithSandeep using MUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with type assertions and additional variable.

```
const handleUniverseChange = (item: TOption | unknown) => {
    setUniverse(item as TOption);
    const val = item as TOption;
    setValue("universe_id", val.value as string);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The options should be in array and not in object. Kindly try the below code,

```
export type TOption = [{
  label: string | number;
  value: string | number;
}];
```

Comment: Wrong. Error in this line `setValue("universe_id", item.value);` Value does not exist in type `TOption`

Comment: Where does that `item` comes from ?. Are you creating state or something like that ?

Comment: It's coming from react-select. I'm not creating a state.

Comment: Did you try what I have mentioned in the answer ??

Comment: I tried everything which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here lies with useState generic - unknown "dominating" TOption. If `SetStateAction<...>` is intended, change the `unknown` to `null`:

```
const [universe, setUniverse] = useState<SetStateAction<TOption | null>>(null);
```

if `SetStateAction<...>` is not intended:

```
const [universe, setUniverse] = useState<TOption | null>(null);
```

and then try

```
const handleUniverseChange = (item: TOption) => {
   ...
}
```

**EDIT**

The type is inferred from the passed options so make sure it is clear that your passed options are of the desired type (f.ex. `TOption[]`)

```
export type TOption = {
    label: string | number;
    value: string | number;
};

const universes: TOption[] = [
    { label: "test", value: 0 },
    { label: "test2", value: 1 },
];

const App = () => {
    const handleChange = (item: TOption | null) => {
        if (!item) return;

        console.log(item); // {label: ..., value: ...}
    };

    return <Select onChange={handleChange} options={universes} />;
};
```

Comment: When I change paremeter in function `handleUniverseChange` differ from `unknown`, I'll get an error from this line `onChange={handleUniverseChange}`
`Error: Type "(item: TOption) => void" can't assign for "(newValue: unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta) => void".`

Comment: If I set there as parameter `unknown | TOption` then i get an error in this line `setValue("universe_id", item.value);` Error is ->  `object type is unknown`

Comment: Changing the type in your use state call makes no difference?

Comment: yup, exactly.[5 symbols]

Comment: I tried myself and you are right. I see it infers the type based on the items passed, so i managed to get it accept (item: TOption | null) => void. So make sure your universe items are declared as an array of TOption and your state as TOption | null, then it should work without type assertions.

Comment: I don't understand you. Could you please update your answer if its no need for type assertions and no error from typescript then I'll accept it.

Comment: it's updated now.

Comment: Universes is a state. It's not had a default value, it's default value `null`. And I can't just move  it outside component. Sorry, but your updated answer don't correct, and I get same errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246345/discussion-between-dean-and-spectr).

Answer (score 0):

The `SetStateAction` is not required here.

Change the handler to

```
  const handleUniverseChange = (item: TOption | null )  => {}
```

Having said that, TOption feels very wrong. You are making your life difficult by saying label and value can be string | number.

```
type TOption = {
  label: string | number;
  value: string | number;
};
```

Also, i recommend you assign a default value instead of null here

```
  const [universe, setUniverse] = useState<TOption | null>(null);
```

Having nulls floating around is never a good idea.